# How to waterproof this shower window

Tags: bathroom, windows, waterproofing

I removed a lot of unknown gooey stuff that formed a seal between the outer plastic edges, the window itself, and the wooden quarter-round moulding that was nailed to the frame (and completely rotten at the bottom). There is now a 3/4 inch (2 cm) gap with pink insulation inside, 1 inch at the bottom.

By the way in all the videos I watched, I haven't seen pink insulation used in the gap.

**How can I best fill and seal this?** Is the damage on the wood in the corners OK to leave there, as long as I seal it properly?

Looks like all the damage is from the inside shower water, not from outside.

[image: entire tub window]
[image: wood damage at the bottom corner]
[image: another view of the bottom corner]
[image: the opposite bottom corner]

Comment: How solid is the wood in the corners?

Comment: @JD74 not solid, unfortunately. I'm just afraid that if I touch it, I'll have to rip out at least some the tiles.

Comment: Kinda looks to me like water can get behind the window casing.

Comment: @Huesmann do you mean the third photo, from the right side of the casing? If yes than you have a point, I didn't notice this before. That's possibly the cause of all the rot in the corner.

Comment: @montrealist yes, the pic that shows the cracks between the casing and tile.  Not sure if that's grouted (wrong material) or caulked (right material but can get old and dry).